# Upgrading Apache from 2.4.6 to 2.4.41 on Centos 7

Tags: centos, apache-httpd

I would like to seek some guidance on how to upgrade httpd 2.4.6 to 2.4.41 on centos 7. I realised there are similar questions but for RHEL7. The reason for upgrade is due to vulnerability CVE-2017-9788, CVE-2014-3523 for httpd-2.4.6.

How should I go about upgrading the versions? Do I need to build from the the source zip? And would I need to do any symlink or PATH variable or things like that? Do I need to copy the current configuration to new installation path? Sorry if I sounded a bit amateur because I have little experience in this area.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: sorry about that, ya, should be upgrading

Comment: can I do yum install httpd? I did not dare to execute that in fear that it would break something, so I wanted some guidance on how to do it safely.

Comment: See the link just above; these CVEs have been fixed in the CentOS package of httpd 2.4.6 (the fixes have been backported; 2.4.6-67.el7_4.2 has [the fix for CVE-2017-9788](https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2017:2479)), or weren’t relevant in the first place (CVE-2014-3523 is a Windows-only vulnerability).

Comment: This is actually an instruction from the security team, we kind of need to do that. I guess there is no harm in upgrading the version? Just wondering whether I can do a simple yum install httpd.

Comment: I did a sudo yum install httpd, it says nothing to do. and I checked the version still remain the same.

Comment: If the *full* package version is 2.4.6-67 or later, the CVEs are fixed. The whole point of using a distribution with some level of support is that the distribution’s maintainers take care of security updates for you. You can always choose to install httpd manually, but that won’t provide any additional fix for these CVEs, and then you’ll be responsible for keeping httpd up to date if any other vulnerability is discovered in the future.

Comment: Tell your security team to read (and take the time to understand) [this CentOS FAQ](https://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/General#A_PCI_audit_says_I_am_running_a_version_which_has_CVE_exploits_in_it) and the linked articles.

Comment: Thanks @StephenKitt, I will update the team about this. I did verify that CVEs are fixed by using rpm -q --changelog httpd. Thanks.